# GCE alerting when one of created metrics is absent (via terraform)

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

I have configured alert policies via terraform which included CPU/Memory and other alerting (many of them). Unfortunately, i have faced with issue when one of my GCE instance became unresponsive - i am receiving lot of alerts in my Slack because i have configured condition_absent block for all my policies.

For example:

```
    condition_absent {
      duration = "360s"
      filter   = "metric.type=\"custom.googleapis.com/quota/gce\" resource.type=\"global\""

      aggregations {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
        group_by_fields = [
          "metric.label.metric",
          "metric.label.region",
        ]
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_MEAN"
      }
```

```
    condition_absent {
      duration = "360s"
      filter          = "metric.type=\"agent.googleapis.com/memory/percent_used\" resource.type=\"gce_instance\" metric.label.\"state\"=\"used\""

      aggregations {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
        per_series_aligner = "ALIGN_MEAN"
      }
```

My question is following: Can i create one condition_absent block in terraform instead of many and send one notification instead of tons in case one of metrics stopped to work?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by adding Monitoring Agent Uptime metric alert. It's correctly showing when the VM is inaccessible (under overload etc.)